# Download Image file Problem using React.js.

Tags: javascript, reactjs

On click of download button, the file gets download but on opening it shows "Cant open this file"

```
    import * as React from 'react';
    import Child from './child';
    export interface Props {
    }
    export interface State {

    }
    export default class Parent extends React.Component<Props, State> {
        constructor(props: Props) {
            super(props);
        }
        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                     <Child url="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260"/>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    enter code here

    // Here is the Child Component

import * as React from 'react';
export interface Props {
    url: string;
}
export interface State {

}
export default class Child extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
        this.download = this.download.bind(this);
    }
    download() {
        debugger;
        var element = document.createElement('a');
        var file = new Blob([this.props.url], { type: 'image/*' });
        element.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        element.download = 'image.jpg';
        element.click();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <img src={this.props.url} />
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <span onClick={() => { this.download(); }}>Download</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: where you want store the downloaded image?

Comment: with a url you can simply run 
`element.href = this.props.url` without using a blob. or else make an XMLHTTPRequest, make a blob with the response and then download

Comment: I tried using XMLHTTPRequest and did a get Call but then also it gave me the same error "Cant open the file".

Comment: I want store the image file in my PC by downloading it like we do for csv .